# string creating for jsonb query using psycopg2

Tags: python, string, psycopg2, psql, jsonb

I have following query with works in db

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM data
WHERE name ='user' AND
      dt > date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) AND 
      submited_jsonb @> '{"Type":["New"]}'
GROUP BY mage, date_trunc('day', dt)
```

Now following in my python version where I have to pass just name

```
query = """SELECT count(*) as count
           FROM data
           WHERE name ='{0}' AND
                 dt > date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) AND 
                 submited_jsonb @> '{"Type":["New"]}'
           GROUP BY mage, date_trunc('day', dt)""".format(user)
```

However above string thowing following error

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 12))
```

I have reduce error to following line 
'{"Type":["New"]}' in string.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `"...".format()`, so you should double the literal `{}` to escape them.

```
...
submited_jsonb @> '{{"Type":["New"]}}'
...
```